# pacemaker not monitoring the service although giving op monitor interval=10s while creating resource

Tags: failovercluster, rhel7, pacemaker, corosync

Following is the service scripts which runs custom script.

```
[root@xxxxxxxxxxvmrf0001vbisalah001 ~]# cat 
/etc/systemd/system/drbdRes_rhcdDaemon.service
[Unit]
Description=Manage drbdRes cluster service
After=basic.target
Requires=basic.target

[Service]
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/opt/ngms/ha.d/drbdRes_rhcdDaemon.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/ngms/ha.d/drbdRes_rhcdDaemon.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And created resource using below command

```
pcs resource create MNGT_drbdRes_rhcdDaemon systemd:drbdRes_rhcdDaemon op monitor interval=10s --group MNGT
```

Resource will start, but if i kill the process still `pcs resource status`
shows resource has been started.

I have put debug logs in start/stop/status in `/opt/ngms/ha.d/drbdRes_rhcdDaemon.sh` script. Debug logs are generated at start and stop but not at status. I feel resource has been not monitored.